# Excel: Unloading an array of data by condition

Tags: arrays, excel, list, formula

How to get a list (array) of period dates when the accumulated amount becomes negative?

Also interesting is the formula, how to find the first / last date at which the accumulated amount becomes negative?

The task must be solved using standard Excel functions (without auxiliary columns, VBA, DAX).

I suspect that the tasrk can be solved using the MATCH function. But it is not exactly.

Example: https://transfiles.ru/m6u31

Comment: Question is quiet unclear. Post few sample data and then show your desired output.

Comment: I added an example (excel file is available for download from the link)

Comment: https://transfiles.ru/m6u31